# Grab Handles by Three-Finger Tap not working after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: multi-touch, synaptics, grab-handles

I recently upgrade my Ubuntu installation from 11.10 to 12.04.

Before the upgrade I was able to use three-finger tapping to bring up the grab-handles. Unfortunately, after the upgrade, that functionality is broken, since I cannot use the three-finger tap anymore.

Because the touchpad settings in ubuntu are somewhat limited, I don't really know what to do right now.

I hope someone can help me with that. I'll be glad to provide more info if needed.

> > Edit: The issue is not the gesture, but the binding of grab handles.
> >
> > In CCSM, I cannot assign the middle-click to the grab-handle toggle.

Comment: I successfully reenabled the three-finger tap by installing synaptiks from the software-center and reassigning the middle-click.

Comment: post your comments as an answer, then mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real answer but a workaround. Here is what i did:

- reenable middle-click with synaptiks from software center
- assign a keyboard-shortcut to grab handles with ccsm

Kind of disappointing though, since it worked out of the box on 11.10